# Vue 2 With Jquery Chosen

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Trying to use jquery-chosen with vue, the problem is that this plugin hides the actual select that I applied v-model, so when I select a value vue doesn't recognize it as a select change event and model value is not updated.

I've seen some solution available for Vue 1 that don't work with Vue 2

It's showing the current value but doesn't know how to set so that model value changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/q21ygz3h/

```
Vue.directive('chosen', {
 twoWay: true, // note the two-way binding
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {

Vue.nextTick(function() {
  $(el).chosen().on('change', function(e, params) {
    alert(el.value);
  }.bind(binding));
});
},
    update: function(el) {
// note that we have to notify chosen about update
// $(el).trigger("chosen:updated");
 }
  });

var vm = new Vue({
 data: {
   cities: ''
 }
 }).$mount("#search-results");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The preferred method of integrating jQuery plugins into Vue 2 is to wrap them in a component. Here is an example of your Chosen plugin wrapped in a component that handles both single and multiple selects.

```
Vue.component("chosen-select",{
  props:{
    value: [String, Array],
    multiple: Boolean
  },
  template:`<select :multiple="multiple"><slot></slot></select>`,
  mounted(){
    $(this.$el)
      .val(this.value)
      .chosen()
      .on("change", e => this.$emit('input', $(this.$el).val()))
  },
  watch:{
    value(val){
       $(this.$el).val(val).trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
  },
  destroyed() {
      $(this.$el).chosen('destroy');
  }
})
```

And this is an example of usage in a template:

```
<chosen-select v-model='cities' multiple>
  <option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>
  <option value="Orleans">Orleans</option>
  <option value="Denver">Denver</option>
</chosen-select>

<chosen-select v-model='cities2'>
  <option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>
  <option value="Orleans">Orleans</option>
  <option value="Denver">Denver</option>
</chosen-select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q21ygz3h/9/) for multiple select.

**Original Answer**

This component doesn't handle multiple selects correctly, but leaving it here because it was the original answer that was accepted.

```
Vue.component("chosen-select",{
  props:["value"],
  template:`<select class="cs-select" :value="value"><slot></slot></select>`,
  mounted(){
    $(this.$el)
      .chosen()
      .on("change", () => this.$emit('input', $(this.$el).val()))
  }
})
```

This component supports v-model. So that you can use it in your template like so:

```
<chosen-select v-model='cities'>
  <option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>
  <option value="Orleans">Orleans</option>
</chosen-select>
```

Here is your fiddle [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/q21ygz3h/1/).

Comment: Hi Bret, Thankyou for your reply. My problem is that select data is coming from the server, I cannot change the select to chosen-select.

Comment: @wagas Do you mean the options are coming from the server?

Comment: I am using Python Django and the whole form is coming from the server. Because of data inside options changes on every refresh. The only thing I can do is add attributes like v-model etc

Comment: @Waqas You can use `is` to tell Vue to treat a normal `select` as a Chosen select.   http://jsfiddle.net/q21ygz3h/2/

Comment: I think that will do the trick. Thank you for your help. I just started Vue 2 days ago so don't have much experience.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for `<select multiple>`. See [my jsfiddle fork](http://jsfiddle.net/tylercollier/1h9fqoae/) and note problems:
1. Select Toronto, then Orleans, then Denver. The Chosen selection looks correct, but the value is wrong: it's only Denver.
2. Pick 2 values, then use the 'x' to remove one. Again, the Chosen part looks correct, but the value is wrong - it's empty, when it should still have one city.

Comment: It works! Great, thanks! I recommend you take out the version that doesn't work with `multiple`.

Comment: @Bert: It doesn't update for option tag bound like this `<option v-for="(state, index) in states" :key="index" :value="state.sid">{{state.nm}}</option>` Any idea how ti fix this?

Comment: @TimLiberty It works fine with `v-for`. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zLqnozxx/1/). I would guess if it doesn't for you that your options are populated asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

For Vue3

```
<template>
    <select><slot></slot></select>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:{
            value: [String, Array],
        },
        mounted() {
            $(this.$el)
            .val(this.value)
            .chosen({disable_search: true})
            .on("change", e => this.$emit('input', $(this.$el).val()))
        },
        watch: {
            value(val){
                $(this.$el).val(val).trigger('chosen:updated');
            }
        },
        destroyed() {
            $(this.$el).chosen('destroy');
        },
    }
</script>
```