# Choose in Vue.js not showing option

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to use Chosen in my vue.js project, but it's not showing computed/created () options in the select tag, however, if I type them manually I get the options, how do I solve this?

plus if I try without adding the chosen class to it, it works fine, if I do, it doesn't show up.

I have included chose.js and choosen.css in my index.html head and footer respectively.

Here is my code.

**Vue.js - template**

```
<select v-model="form.hotel_cat" class="nice-select">
<option>Select Category</option>
<option v-for="options in HotelCategoriesList" :value="options.name" >{{options.name}}</option>
</select>
```

vue.js Script

```
 export default {
        components: {AccountSideBar},
        data(){
            return {
                form : {
                    hotel_name  : null,
                    hotel_cat : null,
                },
                HotelCategoriesList: {},
            }
        },


        methods: {
            submit(){
                axios.post('/api/auth/hotel-add/user--add-hotel', this.form)
                    .then(res => {
                        this.form.init_code = res.data.init_code;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.data.response.error)
                        //console.log(error.data.response.errors);
                })
            },
        }
    }
```

chosen.js library : https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: please give the link of the website of that library

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim was actually trying other method, didn't work tho, updated my question

Comment: where do you initialize the `Chosen` plugin.  It should be put in `mounted` function .

Comment: I didn't initialise it in the mounted,  included it in my script.js file

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641153/vue-2-with-jquery-chosen