# How can I call a function when Vue modifies the DOM?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a `select` box that shows one or the other `select` box when its value changes:

```
<form id="reportForm">
    <select class="form-control chosen-enabled"
            v-model="selectedDataType">
        <option value="First">Show First</option>
        <option value="Second">Show Second</option>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control chosen-enabled"
            v-if="selectedDataType === 'First'">
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control chosen-enabled"
            v-if="selectedDataType === 'Second'">
        <option value="foo">Foo</option>
        <option value="baz">Baz</option>
        <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The Vue js is dead simple:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#reportForm',
    data() {
        return {
            selectedDataType: '',
        }
    }
});
```

**All of this is working fine.**

However, I am *also* using the [Chosen JQuery library](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) which is activated by calling `$('.some-selector').chosen()`.

When these DOM elements are added by Vue, they're new and need to have the `$(...).chosen()` method called on them to enable the tasty Chosen goodness.

*How can I show/hide DOM elements without breaking Chosen?*

Comment: I tested a few different ways and wrapping it in a component like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641153/vue-2-with-jquery-chosen) and binding a `key` to each `<chosen-select />` seemed to get it to work.

Comment: You could use `v-show` instead of `v-if`. That way, the elements will exist in the document

Comment: @Phil post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.  Yours is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the *Chosen* jQuery plugin requires the elements to exist in the document, you're better off controlling the display using `v-show` instead of `v-if`.

This means your elements will always be in the document so the jQuery plugin can operate on them.

```html
<select class="form-control chosen-enabled" v-show="selectedDataType === 'First'">
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control chosen-enabled" v-show="selectedDataType === 'Second'">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="baz">Baz</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

Answer (score 1):

use watcher function  watcher watch for certain variable change and then rerun the respective method you can read about it here

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html